# BCD and numbers

Tags: karnaugh-map

i should do a BCD numbers that has 2,3,6,8. I did it.

Sometimes it asks me to do BCD that has 3,6,9.

I lost my way with 3,6,9. How?

As far as i did 2 is on binary 0010 the 3 is 0011 the 6 is 0101 i should use only those numbers all whole until 15?

Could you explain me what i will do because in 4bits b0,b1,b2,b3?

it asks me logic array, karnaugh map, logical chart.

What i did is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufx3E.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRGLN.jpg.

What i will do in case it is 3,6,9 numbers it asks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: 6 is 0110  and BCD (D=decimal) number only go from 0 to 9 i.e. 0000 to 1001. Anything above 9 is not BCD

Comment: "Sometimes it asks me" what is *it*? Is it sentient?

Comment: There are two exercises on i did and it is right ,the problem is with the 3,6,9.Second,i didnt knew that on bcd that it isnt because in a book M.MORRIS MANO shows it that it has until 15.I know that 3,6,9 on binary but i use ONLY those?on the picture i shouldnt wrote whole numbers until 15?

Comment: sorry is my first use here in this site as i had did a lot of search and read.I can confess i didnt understand about after 9 it isnt BCD

Comment: When i say 3,6,9 numbers on BCD i mean it ask me to do the same exercise but with this numbers.I did only for 2,4 etc

Comment: @ek.Nik, please put spaces between sentences. ... do you use sentence structure in your language?

Comment: note: in the first picture, you show binary 1010 up to 1111 which you marked as 10,11,12,13,14,15 ... you should really use `hexadecimal` which would mark those same values as A,B,C,D,E,F ... 0-9 are still the same ...... bin 1010 = hex A

Comment: I'm having serious issues with understanding anything. It's like I know all the words, but added together they don't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really follow your question, but e.g. 3, 6 and 9 will be translated as:

```
    8421

3   0011        2+1
6   0110      4+2
9   1001    8+    1
```

So e.g. 69 becomes 0110 1001

Note that only 100 values are used (0..9) followed by another (0..9). This means every nibble (4 bits), both left and right can only have values of 0..9. Values from 1010 to 1111 are illegal in BCD.

Comment: thanks i didn't knew that,but my exercises ask me to use only 3,6,9 those only numbers on 4bit so i can create it.